# LED light dimming problem

Tags: led, dimmer-switch

I have problem with my recessed LED lights. I am using retrofit LED lights which is connected with can housing via TP24 connector.

I have configured dimmer switch so that when I slide dimmer all the way down, lights will stay lit at around 5-10% light output. Most of the time it works just fine, but sometimes when I slide dimmer down, 2 of 4 lights will be turned off completely, even before the slider reaches all the way down, other 2 lights will be at 5-10% range as expected.

Last time when it happened, I tried switching lights (to check if it is light problem or wiring/dimmer problem) between cans. Light with problem continued to have problem at new location. Light without problem worked fine at new location as well. So it looks like light itself has the problem. Can someone tell me what could be wrong with light ? These are brand new lights I ordered from amazon.

[Please check the video recording of the problem.](https://tinyurl.com/yxhd8ur5)

2 lights on the right side in video (near top right and bottom right corner) are having problem.

LED light model: dl_bfdr4-11w-3k-10pk
Dimmer model: LUTRON AYCL-153PH

Comment: I was going to say: Sorry, the dimmer isn't on the light's compatibility list. But I checked, and it is. But the light is **not** on the dimmer's list. Go to Lutron and see if you can find a suitable light on their list.

Comment: I take when you say you "configured the dimmer", you mean you adjusted the *low-end trim*?

Comment: I'm concerned with quality here. I've searched the brand for any presence in bricks-n-mortar stores, and all I find is junk-dumping websites: eBay, Amazon Marketplace, overstock.com, and the part number really scraped bottom of barrel: ubuy.co.th, desertcart, gistgear.com, savemoney.es etc.  Walmart and Sears came up, but they were simply feeds of Amazon and eBay 3rd party listings.  This usually indicates low quality and non-UL-listed (i.e. not safe).

Comment: Although I agree with Harper on junk from china different brands of lamps may dim differently based on the driver technology in use , wattage , lumens per watt there are lots of things that could cause differences in the dimming of even high quality lamps. The simple one is a lamp that is 100 lumens per watt compared to a 130 lumens per watt both lamps may be 10 watts but the 100 lumen per watt lamps will not have any visible light long before the 130 lumen per watt lamp. The junk lamps are old technology so they put out less light today we should compare lumens per watt and go for the big #.